# System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on QueueSobject

Tags: apex, unit-test, dml, queue

I am trying to insert a QueueSObject in test class but getting the error

> System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on QueueSobject

This code was working before but started giving error recently:

```
Group g1 = new Group(Name='collection', type='Queue');
insert g1;
QueuesObject q1 = new QueueSObject(QueueID = g1.Id, SobjectType = 'Task');
insert q1;
Collections_Queue__c c1 = new Collections_Queue__c(Queue_ID__c = g1.Id);
insert c1;
```

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Summer ’20 and later, only authenticated internal and external users can access this object.

A queue is a Group whose Type is Queue. To create a Group, you must have the Manage Users permission.
[Refer this for more details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_queuesobject.htm)

Comment: How can enable this setting for my User. Is it a Profile level or a user level?

Comment: It is available at profile level under Administrative Permissions.

Comment: Thanks, the code was running in a different profile context due to which error was occuring.